# A question on Markov chain

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory, information-theory

Suppose for two random variables $X$ and  $Y$ we have $X\perp\!\!\!\perp Y$ and also assume that three random variables  $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ form the following Markov chain: $X\to Z\to Y$.
Do these two assumptions imply that $Z$ is a constant?

I know that this is true that if   $X\perp\!\!\!\perp Y$ then we can have the following trivial Markov chain:  $X\to c\to Y$ where $c$ is a constant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $(X,Z,Y)$ is independent, then $(X,Y)$ is independent and $(X,Z,Y)$ is a Markov chain. Hence $Z$ can be nondegenerate.

Comment: Thanks Did, I did not know that if $(X, Z, Y)$ is independent, then trivially they form the Markov chain $X\to Z\to Y$.